# Is it possible to embed a font on a local website?

Tags: html, css, font-face, webfonts

I'm wanting to embed a font on a local website. This is what I have added to my CSS file.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "SpecialFont";
  src: url("fonts/SpecialFont.ttf");
}

.newfont {
font-family: "SpecialFont", Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

And if I do something like this on a page, the font changes to Times New Roman.

```html
<div class="newfont">This text should be in SpecialFont.</div>
```

Is it not possible to embed a font on a local website? Or am I doing something wrong? It needs to work in at least Firefox and IE11.

Comment: yes it's possible: look at the network panel inside the console and check the response of the font

Comment: Did you actually download font?

Comment: does `fonts/SpecialFont.ttf` actually exist on server?

Comment: What do you mean by "local website"? Do you mean something with "file://" as the scheme, or something with "http://localhost" as the host name?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Does it matter? Both get parsed right?

Comment: A request for `url("fonts/SpecialFont.ttf")` may run afoul of CORS if the "file://" scheme is used.

Comment: @fcalderan I don't have a network panel. These are just files sitting on a networked folder.

Comment: @SergChernata Yes. I have the font downloaded already, but not everyone who views this site will have it downloaded.

Comment: @HereticMonkey My office uses an internal website that is composed of files on a networked folder.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Just tested it in latest version of Chrome and FF and both work fine with `file://`

Comment: @Robby, your code works for me on my network drive. Maybe the ttf file is corrupt? What is the status on the ttf file?

Comment: @MarkBaijens How do I get the http status?

Comment: Network tap of the developer console in chrome. Ff has something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert font to web, use Font Squirrel, it will generate all fonts and css files: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: This is working for me in Firefox, but not IE11. The demo files in the downloaded zip even display the font in Times New Roman, which was the same issue I had to begin with.

Comment: Don't think ie11 supports ttf

Comment: It looks like Font Squirrel converted the ttf to woff and woff2 though. Do those not work with IE11 either?

Comment: @Robby From a quick google search it looks like woff is supported, but it can also be a bit problematic (as we are used to from ie). You can try with eot, that should work.

Answer (score -1):

You can define different font types to have a fallback for older browsers who don't support latest files. I did the font declaration like this to cover old browser support (of course make sure you have all the needed files).

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "fontname";
    src: url("/folder/font.eot");
    src: url("/folder/font.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("/folder/font.woff") format("woff"),
    url("/IS_MyQuantosTheme/font.svg#font") format("svg");
}
```